# Sample Ruby Code To Create A Database/UserIn Postgresql

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I would greatly appreciate if someone can provide me sample Ruby code to create a database and a user in postgresql. I am assuming this is probably very straightforward for experienced users. I have found sample code to query existing databases but not for creating a new database with a user.

Below is the sample code:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "database_1", "databse_1_user", "")

res  = conn.exec('select tablename, tableowner from pg_tables')
```

Answer (score 0):

First log into postgres from the command line, depending on your OS:

```
su - postgres
```

Or maybe just

```
psql
```

Then you'll need to create a user (or a role as postgres refers to it) than can create a database for you to connect to.

```
create role YOURUSERNAME with createdb login password 'YOURPASSWORD';
```

Then create the database

```
create database MYDATABASE OWNER=YOURUSERNAME;
```

Then you should be able to log in from ruby with:

```
conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "#{MYDATABASE}", "#{YOURUSERNAME}", "")
enter code here
```

Comment: I am trying to create the database and the user from the ruby code. I am not trying to connect to an existing database but create a new one with a ruby script.